# why does one method destroy my linked list while another does not?

Tags: java, linked-list, singly-linked-list

I have seen similar questions asked, but none of the answers really address my confusion.

I'm working through some Linked List content, trying to write methods to solve leetcode-like problems. I'm working with singly-linked lists, defined as:

```
public class LinkedListy {
ListNode head;
LinkedListy(){};

   public static class ListNode { 
      int val; //integer variable
      ListNode next; //pointer

      ListNode() {} 

      ListNode(int val) { 
          this.val = val; 
      }

      ListNode(int val, ListNode next) { 
          this.val = val; this.next = next; 
      }
  }
  ...
```

I'm trying to write a function that will reverse my linked list, but will not destroy my original linked list. The code I have written works to reverse the list, but destroys the original list:

```
public ListNode reverse() {
    //use copyList function to avoid altering head --> DOESN'T WORK
    ListNode current = head;
    ListNode temp = null;
    ListNode copied_result = null;

    while(current != null){
        temp = current.next;
        current.next = copied_result;
        copied_result = current;
        current = temp;
    }
    return copied_result;
}
```

From reading on here and other places, I understand that by setting current = head, I'm just creating a new reference for the same ListNode. Thus, when I run my code, I'm mutating the original list.

**Main Confusion: I'm confused because I have written methods that do NOT destroy the original list, but use the same kind of reference to head.** For example, in my "length()" method, I set dummy = head and alter dummy to find the length of the list. But, then the original list doesn't get changed (I wrote a print function to print the list and I verified it prints the same before and after calling length().)

```
    public int length() {
    ListNode dummy = head;
    int length = 0;
    while(dummy != null) {
        dummy = dummy.next;
        length++;
    }
    return length;
}
```

So, I'm clearly not understanding something fundamental about LinkedLists.

1. Why does my reverse() method destroy the original list when my length() method does not?
2. Is the only way to write a reverse method for a linked list without destroying the original list to make a copy of the original list in your main method and reverse the copy?

Any help or resources would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: `current.next = copied_result;` writes a value to `next` whereas `dummy = dummy.next;` just reads from `next` without affecting the value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the `length` method, you're using a locally accessible variable named `dummy` to iterate through the nodes in the list; when you set `dummy = dummy.next`, this sets the value of the local variable to refer to the `next` node. This is very different from doing something like `dummy.next = null`, which would affect the content of node to which dummy currently refers.

To that end, your `reverse` method doesn't actually 'destroy' the original list - the main issue is that `head` isn't being set to the first element when you're finished. Thus, `head` still 'points' to the same node it did before the function started, which is now the last node.

If you want to reverse the list in-place, then just updating `head` properly at the end of your function will work fine - if you want to return a reversed copy of your original list without modifying the original, you'll need to copy all of the nodes. See @Hank_interprize's description of deep/shallow copies.

Comment: Ah thank you! I can totally see the difference between the two methods now- changing what the variable references vs changing the actual node. I’ll try your suggestion of updating the head at the end

Answer (score 1):

I believe the issue here is you are not actually copying any new information over to the new list but instead the code is just using the same list as before under a new name. This can be done with a deep copy.

[image]

To create a new list you will need to copy the old data over to a new list with a whole new system of pointers and simply copying the data over to the new linked list which is different than copying the pointer.